# How to simulate user selection of a Spinner option

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a Spinner that selects different commands to be run. I would like to programmatically simulate the user selecting a command (and running it).

Is this possible? Can it be done both visibly and invisibly (without showing the Spinner drop down and the simulated finger touch to select the command)?

Comment: You can use `Spinner.setSelection(int position)`. I don't think this can be done visibly

Comment: So `.setSelection()` not only sets the selection but calls the `onItemSelected()` listener?

Comment: Probably, if it doesn't you can call it yourself too by saving it into a global variable.

Comment: Thanks. setSelection() seems to do the job invisibly. Wish there was a way to do it with visible UI.

Answer (score 1):

As I said, you can call `Spinner.setSelection(int position)` to invisibly select an item

To visibly select it, you can try calling `spinner.performClick()` which should open the dropdown, then call `spinner.setSelection(index)`. If dropdown is still opened after that you can try calling your activity's `onBackPressed()` to close it.